# TFlowLayout order

Tags: android, forms, delphi, layout

I work on Delphi 11 to develop an Android App

> I want to use a TFlowLayout, to position TButton, TLabel and TPath , and be
> able to change the spacing between them easily.

Unfortunately when I place them in the TFlowLayout container, I can no longer modify the order, if I move them in the designer they returns to their position?
**How can I impose the order**?

Comment: Use the Alignment Order dialog for the TFlowLayout. Right click in an empty area of the layout and select Alignment Order or double left click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controls in a TFlowLayout are flowed in alignment order. There is an Alignment Order dialog to change the order. Several ways to bring it up.

1. In the Structure view: click on the FlowLayout to make sure it is selected, then right click and select Alignment Order.
2. In the form editor: right click a free area of the FlowLayout and select Alignment Order.
3. In the form editor: double click a free area of the FlowLayout.

[image]

Comment: Thank you . I didn't see this option in the documentation.